# How to implement Custom function in CKeditor.?

Tags: jquery, html

i am try to implement custom function in `CKeditor` but i cant do that any one have idea.  I am using jquery function.

**HTML**

```
First Name
</br>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<br/>
Second Name
</br>
<input type="text"id="field" />
<br/>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1">
  <div id="fname">name</div>
</textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#name').blur(function ()
{
    if ($('#field').val().length > 0)
    {
        txt = $(this).val() + '\n' + $('#field').val();
    }
    else 
    {
        txt = $('#name').val();
    }   

    $('#fname').text(txt);
}); 

$('#field').blur(function () {
    txt = '';
    txt = $('#name').val() + '\n' + $(this).val();
    $('#fname').text(txt);
});
```

this jquery function i want implement in text-area this function show the result of text-fields in text-area.